# Read .feature file in cucumber and copy content to new feature file

Tags: java, parsing, cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

Suppose, I have numerous scenarios under 1 feature file- *GamePlay.feature*.

```
Feature: Game play

@TestCase_1 @Regression
 Scenario: Breaker joins a game
    Given the Maker has started a game with the word "silky"
    When the Breaker joins the Maker's game
    Then the Breaker must guess a word with 5 characters

@TestCase_2 @Regression 
 Scenario: Breaker joins a game
    Given the Maker has started a game with the word "soft"
    When the Breaker joins the Maker's game
    Then the Breaker must guess a word with 4 characters

.
.
. and many more
```

Let's say I want to copy the test steps of Test case #2(Scenario, Given, When, Then) and paste them into new feature file (*GameLost.feature*).
I'll search the scenario based on tags (For Ex -@TestCase_2)
The new feature file *GameLost.feature* should look like -

```
Feature: Game lost

@TestCase_2 @Regression 
 Scenario: Breaker joins a game
    Given the Maker has started a game with the word "soft"
    When the Breaker joins the Maker's game
    Then the Breaker must guess a word with 4 characters
```

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can take benefit of [bdd generator](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd_generator.html) with [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber). You should run in dry run mode with meta-data filter and generated files will have scenarios only with those meta-data (tags). BDD Generator generates feature file from your test authored  in `.bdd`, `.feature` or `.java` file. If required, you can create your custom implementation same as [BDDGenerator](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/report/BDDGenerator.java).